# how to pass several variables to url from multiselect form

Tags: jquery, forms

Until now I only get urlparameter=1&urlparameter=2. But how may I pass variables from  a multiselect-form to parameters of the url like
myurl.tld?urlparameter1=1&urlparameter2=2.

// How do I chanche the url from first to second version:

urlparameter=1&urlparameter=2

urlparameter1=1&urlparameter2=2

// I use html

```
<select name="garden[]" multiple="multiple" id="garden">
  <option value="1" name="urlparameter1">Flowers</option>
  <option value="2" name="urlparameter2">Trees</option>
</select>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

// and I use jquery

```
$("#garden").change(function () { 
  var id = $(this).attr('name');
  var str2 = "";
$("#garden option:selected").each(function () {

   str2 += "&"+id+"="+ $(this).attr('value');             
   });
  $(".two").text(str2);
})
.trigger('change');
```

// samplecode here

http://jsfiddle.net/8ru47abb/

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The whole idea of the multiselect is to have `garden[]` show up on the server side as an array of the selected options. Then you loop through the array server side.

Comment: I need the different values - connected with a name - for later use in an sql-statement with phpgrid.  I need to use it like 

     urlparameter1=1&urlparameter2=2. But now I get only garden[]=1&garden[]=2 Even this  form would help me: garden[urlparameter1]=1&garden[urlparameter2]=2

Answer (score 0):

Just modified your code a little to do it.

Working jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8ru47abb/1/

HTML

```
<select name="garden[]" multiple="multiple" id="garden">
  <option value="1" name="urlparameter1">Flowers</option>
  <option value="2" name="urlparameter2">Plants</option>
  <option value="6" name="urlparameter3">Trees</option>
</select>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

Script

```
$("#garden").change(function () { 
    var id = $(this).attr('name').replace("[]","");
     var str2 = "";
     var i = 0;
    $("#garden option:selected").each(function () {

       str2 += "&"+id+ (++i) + "="+ $(this).attr('value');             
       });
      $(".two").text(str2);
    })
    .trigger('change');
```

Comment: Thank you! How would it be possible to change the &garden1 according to selection? Until now everything is "&garden1",  but I need when changing also the parameters "&urlparameter1 and &urlparameter2"

Comment: May you still tell: How may I transfer these variables to the url?